# PHP - Is it possible to create a video (any format) from a list of images using PHP?

Tags: php, video

I want to create a simple video slideshow using a list of images I have automatically using PHP. Is there some sort of library that allows video creation on PHP (like a PHP-GD library but for videos)? If it doesn't exist on PHP, what sort of language would allow easy video creation from pictures?

Also, if there was a way to include sound in the video, that would be even better. Thanks!

Comment: I am unaware of anything beside FFMPEG (http://www.ffmpeg.org/ and http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/), which is not strictly a PHP library.

Comment: Are you sure you need a video slideshow?  If you're showing it online, then a javascript based slideshow will a) be easier b) involve less (server) CPU and c) be more portable.

Comment: @ElYobo. That's a better idea. Thanks! Do you know any good javascript slideshows that allow audio also?

Comment: Audio is probably more difficult.  Google is your friend though - http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+slideshow+audio#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=jquery+audio+&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=e793061d618b37d9 and http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+slideshow+audio#hl=en&expIds=17259,27586,27744&xhr=t&q=jquery+slideshow&cp=15&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0s&aqi=&aql=&oq=jquery+slidewho&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=e793061d618b37d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [PHP Video toolkit](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a ffmpeg command line by PHP.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

For example, below command create a slideshow video with blend effect from 5 images

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 4.jpg \
-c:v libx264 \
-filter_complex " \
[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

You can check below memo for other effect [ffmpeg memo](https://github.com/letungit90/ffmpeg_memo)