# PHP modules/methods for getting frames out of movies

Tags: php, module, movie

I have a whole load of movies in the .mp4 variety, can someone recommend a way to automatically generate thumbnails for these from selected frames in the clip.

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Is it possible to create a video (any format) from a list of images using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385142/php-is-it-possible-to-create-a-video-any-format-from-a-list-of-images-using-p) and [some others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+thumbnails+from+movies+php)

Comment: @Gordon - not a dup of the first (it's the opposite process - pulling out of a movie, rather than putting into a move), but there are definitely dups in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question: [PHP - Is it possible to create a video (any format) from a list of images using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385142/php-is-it-possible-to-create-a-video-any-format-from-a-list-of-images-using-p) has some answers that you could use:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html

and

http://www.effectmatrix.com/total-video-converter-command-line/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), it can convert movies to Flash Video(FLV) and create thumbnails to your specifications.